# Datepicker calendar control asp.net for visual studio 2005

Tags: asp.net, calendar, datepicker

Does anybody know of a good datepicker calendar control for asp.net 2005? I went through a few but can't one that I like.  The biggest problem I'm finding is, how do I clear a date after I picked it?

Thank you,
-Tesh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try [jquery datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) :)

Its good, and it will solve your problem of clearing the date too and lots of cool themes :)

hope it helps

**EDIT :**

use this function inside the script :-

```
 $(function () {
        $("#txtDate").datepicker();
    });
```

this in page

```
 <td>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 </td>
```

also include all proper css and js files as per theme selected. you can directly link the files on internet or can store individual js/css files locally and then reference it.

Also see pagesource of this [link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/default.html). it will further clarify your concepts :)

Comment: Looks nice.  Thanks.  So I need to put the date picker in a repeater and then get the value back.  How would I do this with this date picker?

Comment: add id of repeater in the script . it will return the value :)

Comment: Not following. My assumption is that if controls have the runat="server" and has an id, then I can retrieve that value.  How does it work for this datepicker?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [jQuery Date Picker](http://www.west-wind.com/jqueryweb/jqueryDatepicker.aspx) by Rick Strahl.  It's the only one I ever use.  It's very simple.

Comment: I checked out the control.  Looks nice.  Thanks.

Comment: So, I put this into a repeater and I noticed the second time the control is used in the repeater the calendar button image button does not show up.  Any ideas?

Comment: you may need to set the id of the control in the code behind.  That usually happens if there are two DatePicker controls on the page with the same ID.  View the Generated source of the browser window to confirm my suspicions.